# Run custom callback without run_callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am trying to create around initialize callback for benchmarks.

```
class BaseProcessor
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks

  define_callbacks :initialize
  set_callback :initialize, :around, :run_benchmark

protected

  def run_benchmark
    @benchmark = Benchmark.realtime do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Then other classes are inherited from this BaseProcessor

```
class Child < BaseProcessor
  def initialize
    run_callbacks :initialize do
      # some stuff
    end
  end
end
```

So in every child I have to invoke run_callbacks. So my question is: can I avoid it?

Comment: Why not just use the existing `after_initialize` callback?

Comment: You want `run_callbacks` all the time, but  you don't wan't to write it each time. Right?

Comment: @max every time I add new child I should write run_callbacks

Comment: @NikitaMisharin yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. Something like this should work even without around callbacks.

```
class BaseProcessor

  def self.new(*args)
    Benchmark.realtime do
      super
    end
  end
end
```